# How to pass python callable as an argument of type "block" into a objc method

Tags: python, objective-c, pyobjc

I have a objc method like this;

```
@ implementation of Class1

- (void)execute:(void (^)(Class2* target, NSUInteger idx))block
{
... 

}
```

I want to use this execute method in python, i have build a python objective-c bridge data and it seems to be generated correctly as:

```
<class name='Class1'>
<method selector='execute:'>
<arg function_pointer='true' type='@?' index='0'>
    <arg type='@'/>
    <arg type='I' type64='Q'/>
    <retval type='v'/>
</arg>
</method>
```

But when i define a function like this:

```
def myFunc (dev, index):
    // do something with dev
    print("Hello")
```

and try to use this as block

```
class1_obj.execute_(myFunc)
```

Python throw an errors as:

```
objc.BadPrototypeError: Objective-C expects 1 arguments, Python argument has 2 arguments for <unbound selector myFunc at 0x105b3a3f0>
```

I also tried with lambda function, no use.

I also tried to create a callable class as:

```
>>> class myCallable(object):
...     def __init__(self,name):
...             print "Init"
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return "string init"
...     def __call__(self, dev, index):
...             # do something with dev
...             print("hello")
```

but python throw an error like this:

```
TypeError: Sorry, cannot create IMP for instances of type myCallable
```

I am wondering where did I do wrong here?

Comment: I haven't used this in a long time, but as I recall, the `<arg function_pointer='true' type='@?' index='0'>` should instead be `<arg block='true' index='0'>`. I'm not at all sure that will solve your problem, though. How did you generate that metadata?

Comment: i generate the data according to one of your post actually. use apple commandline tool gen_bridge_metadata as instructed by the apple document.

Comment: It's also funny that if i set the block function takes one argument instead of two, the function will get called. but how to differentiate the two argument...

Comment: Ah, they must have changed the format. Is the BadPrototypeError happening on the line where you call `execute_`, or inside, when you call the "Block"?

Comment: hmm... i am not sure how to tell but here is the output:
>>> multiTarget.execute_(myFunc)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
objc.BadPrototypeError: Objective-C expects 1 arguments, Python argument has 0 arguments for <function myFunc at 0x105af5938>

Comment: it's happening on the line I call execute i think.

Comment: hmm... the parameter got passed in is actually an int, not sure how that happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for Josh's suggestion.

Finally got this problem solved. It looks like the meta_data generated by the system using command line gen_bridge_metadata somehow wasn't read correctly. It was generated as:

```
<method selector='execute:'>
<arg index='0' type='@?' function_pointer='true'>
<arg type='@'/>
<arg type64='Q' type='I'/>
<retval type='v'/>
</arg>
</method>
```

But after I change the function_pointer to block, it works. I got this by reading through pyobjc unit test for blocks.

```
<method selector='execute:'>
<arg index='0' type='@?' block='true'>
<arg type='@'/>
<arg type64='Q' type='I'/>
<retval type='v'/>
</arg>
</method>
```

I am not sure what causes this though. the Apple Doc says if type="@?" and function_pointer='true', it's regarded as block. if type = "#?" and function_pointer="true", it will interpreted as function_pointer. but why pyobjc can't recognize this? is this a bug in pyobjc?

Comment: It _seems_ like PyObjC is doing what the Apple docs say it should (looking for "function_pointer"), if you look at the `switch` inside `PyObjC_processXML()` in [pyobjc-core/Modules/objc/parsexml.m](http://svn.red-bean.com/pyobjc/trunk/pyobjc/pyobjc-core/Modules/objc/parsexml.m), but I still haven't examined this in detail. Are you maybe using an older version of PyObjC?

Comment: hmm. maybe.  I am using the one that comes with Lion 10.7.4 on Mac OS. I am not sure if this is an old copy of it though.

Comment: That should be sufficiently up-to-date. Oh, well. I'll get back to you if I figure anything else out.